# Error on refreshing page after rake db:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

When I run bundle exec rake db:setup and refresh browser(current url for example `http://localhost:3000/xyz`) I get error in ability.rb at this line

```
can :manage, xyz, abc_id: ABC.where(account_id: user.account_id)
```

I know here user is nil thats why its error out but is there a way to avoid this. I was looking to redirect to sign_in if user is nil. Any suggestion what is the best way to deal with this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `NoMethodError - undefined method `account_id' for nil:NilClass:
  app/models/ability.rb:35:in `initialize'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb:357:in `current_ability'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:209:in `current_ability'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:77:in `load_collection?'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:33:in `load_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  cancan (1.6.10) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'`

Comment: How are you initializing `user` in ability.rb ?

Comment: def initialize(user,session)
     `Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    
       user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
       if user.admin?
         can :manage, :all
       else
         can :read, :all
       end`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. All I did check user.nil? and if it is nil do nothing and on else put my old code. So if user is nil it redirects me to login page and thats what I wanted

Comment: Sounds like you were niling out the user variable at some point, are you modifying it in any way?